# How to migrate a RestConfigurationRule from serenity 1.5.11 to 2.6.0

Tags: junit5, serenity-bdd

I'm updating serenity version from 1.5.11 to 2.6.0 in order to be able to run tests with Junit 5, along with serenity-rest-assured dependency. How can I re write this rule below using 2.6.0? Looks like RestConfigurationRule is not present in 2.6.0

```
@Rule
public final RestConfigurationRule rule = new RestConfigurationRule(new TestConfiguration(),
    new LogConfiguration(), new RelaxedHttpsConfiguration());
```

POM :

```
<properties>
    <argLine/>
    <serenity.version>2.6.0</serenity.version>
    <serenity.cucumber.version>1.9.51</serenity.cucumber.version>
    <jackson.version>2.12.1</jackson.version>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.7.0</junit.jupiter.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.fabianlinz</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

[RestConfigurationRule](https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/blob/master/serenity-rest-assured/src/test/java/net/serenitybdd/rest/rules/RestConfigurationRule.java) already exist in last version